# To show the derivative of holomorphic function is not zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that F is a mapping from open set U to complex plane such that F is holomorphic and one-one then show that F'(z) $\ne 0$ for any z $\in U$.
Suppose if we try to prove this by contradiction  that the first derivative is not zero then F is not one-one.
How should I proceed.

Comment: Have you heard of the Local Degree Theorem? It implies that if $F'(z)=0$ then, 'locally' the equation $F(w)=c$ has at least $2$ solutions, which would contradict injectivity (the theorem makes this precise).

Comment: If $F'(a) = 0$ then locally $F(z)$ look like $C (z-a)^n$ for some $n \ge 2$ which is clearly not one to one (the precise meaning of "looks like" is with the biholomorphic maps, leading to the charts of Riemann surfaces)

Answer (score 0):

You need the follwing

THEOREM: Let $G$ be a region in $ \mathbb C$ and $f:G \to \mathbb C$ holomorphic. Let $a \in G$ be a zero of $f-f(a)$ of order $m \ge 1$. Then there is an open subset $V$ of $G$ such that $a \in V$ and:

if $w \in f(V) \setminus \{f(a)\}$, then there are $a_1,...,a_m \in V$ with $f(a_j)=w$ for $j=1,...,m$ and $a_j \ne a_k$ for $j \ne k$.

__

To your question: we can assume that $G:=U$ is a region (why ?).

Assume to the contrary that $F'(a)=0$ for some $a \in G$. Then $F-F(a)$ has a zero of order $m \ge 2$ in $a$. Let $V$ and $w$ as in the THEOREM. Then there are $a_1,a_2 \in V$ such that

$a_1 \ne a_2$ and $F(a_1)=w=F(a_2)$,

a contradiction, since $F$ is one-one.